# Show that index set must be finite

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\{v_k\}_{k \in I}$ be a frame for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|v_k\| = 1$  $\forall k$. Show that $I$ must be finite. I am confused how to proceed, given a frame I know that we have the following inequality:
$$A \|v\|^2 \leq \sum_{k \in I} |\langle v,v_k \rangle|^2 \leq B \|v\|^2, \quad \forall v \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$ But how do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ be the canonical basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$. By Parseval's identity we have have
\begin{align}
nB &= \sum_{j=1}^n B\|e_j\|^2 \ge \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k \in I} |\langle e_j, v_k\rangle|^2 = \sum_{k \in I}\sum_{j=1}^n |\langle e_j, v_k\rangle|^2 = \sum_{k\in I} \|v_k\|^2 = \sum_{k \in I} 1 = |I|.
\end{align}
We see that the cardinality of $I$ is bounded from above by $nB$ and hence $I$ has to be finite.